# Is it possible to export all Bigquery scheduled queries listed into a csv?

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to create programmatic approach in getting the updated Bigquery scheduled queries listed in csv (or Gsheet / Bigquery table if possible). But I cannot find the related documentation for that. For now I can only select all text manually from Bigquery scheduled query page.
Below are the information needed:

- Display name and its URL
- Schedule (UTC)
- Next scheduled
- Author
- destination dataset and destination table

But with the new scheduled query is still being created, it is getting more complicated to track with the list is still growing.

Comment: There is no bigquery information_schema for getting this information. You could webcraw the UI and extract the needed data.

Answer (score 1):

To list the scheduled queries with the bq CLI:

```
bq ls --transfer_config --transfer_location=US --format=prettyjson
```

For viewing the details of a Schedule Query:

```
bq show --transfer_config [RESOURCE_NAME]
# [RESOURCE_NAME] is the value from the above bq ls command
```

In python you can use the below code to list transfer configurations in a project.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery_datatransfer

transfer_client = bigquery_datatransfer.DataTransferServiceClient()

project_id = "my-project"
parent = transfer_client.common_project_path(project_id)

configs = transfer_client.list_transfer_configs(parent=parent)
print("Got the following configs:")
for config in configs:
    print(f"\tID: {config.name}, Schedule: {config.schedule}")
```

For more information you can refer to [link1](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/working-with-transfers) and [link2](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/datatransfer/rest/v1/projects.locations.transferConfigs/list).